# ASP.NET 6 CORS problems after adding IMiddleware for authorizing users

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

Recently, in a project I'm working on, I added a Role creation system. There are many actions in the system and we decided to let the user create their own roles. I added an implementation of IMiddleware where I intercept every single request from the client and see whether or not that api url is included in the actions the user's role has included. The Middleware includes calls to our DB to fetch the user and to validate. I branch either into calling await next.Invoke() or throwing an UnauthorizedAccessException. We also have Fluent Validation in the mix. It frequently uses the same DB when validating and we had no problems, so I don't think the problem lies in the db. I'm uncertain how the Middleware could have interfered with CORS. I scanned the internet, even asked ChatGPT, but to no luck.

Here is the IMiddleware implementation:

```
public class AuthorizationMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    readonly IQueryById Query;

    public AuthorizationMiddleware(IQueryById query)
    {
        Query = query;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        string relativePath = context.Request.Path.Value.Substring(1);
        if (GetWhiteListApiUrls().Contains(relativePath))
        {
            await next.Invoke(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return;
        }
        string requestType = context.Request.Method;
        string protocol = $"{requestType}_{relativePath}";

        var userId = GetUserIdFromHttpContext(context);
        var user = await Query.GetById<User>(userId);
        var roles = await Query.GetByIds<Role>(user.Roles.Select(x => x.Id));
        var actions = roles.SelectMany(x => x.Actions);

        if (!actions.Select(x => x.RelativePathProtocol).Contains(protocol))
            throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();

        await next.Invoke(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

        static string GetUserIdFromHttpContext(HttpContext context)
        {
            string jwt = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer ", "");
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = handler.ReadToken(jwt) as JwtSecurityToken;
            string userId = token.Subject.ToString();
            return Common.IdUtils.GetUserId(userId);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use custom middleware for this purpose? Also can you please provide your CORS set up and the error produced?

Comment: Yes, the particular reason is that I want to have my entire API secured, but cannot predefine roles for authorization as the role creation is left to the user to define and can change at any moment. I must dynamically be able to lock/unlock my api. I get the standard Access to fetch at 'requested_url' from origin 'web_ui_url' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out! We are using ServiceStack. The issue was in ordering of app.UseMiddleware();
The correct ordering is shown below:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Licensing.RegisterLicense(Configuration["ServiceStack:Licence"]);
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost(Configuration)
        {
            AppSettings = new NetCoreAppSettings(Configuration)
        });
        app.UseMiddleware<AuthorizationMiddleware>();
    }
```